# Is there any advantage to reading the entire file

Tags: python, file-io

Are there any advantages/disadvantages to reading an entire file in one go rather than reading the bytes as required? So is there any advantage to:

```
file_handle = open("somefile", rb)
file_contents = file_handle.read()
# do all the things using file_contents
```

compared to:

```
file_handle = open("somefile", rb)
part1 = file_handle.read(10)
# do some stuff
part2 = file_handle.read(8)
# do some more stuff etc
```

Background: I am writing a p-code (bytecode) interpreter in Python and have initially just written a naive implementation that reads bytes from the file as required and performs the necessary actions etc. A friend I was showing the program has suggested that I should instead read the entire file into memory (Python list?) and then process it from memory to avoid lots of slow disk reads. The test files are currently less than 1KB and will probably be at most a few 100KB so I would have expected the Operating System and disk controller system to cache the file obviating any performance issues caused by repeatedly reading small chunks of the file.

Comment: Your friend is right, and your faith in the runtime environment is probably misplaced. It will try to insulate you from the details as best it can, but it will not help that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do any kind of random access then putting it in a list is going to be much faster than seeking from disk. Even if the OS does cache disk access, you are hitting another layer of cache. In any case, you can't be sure how the OS will behave.

Here are 3 cases I can think of that would motivate doing it in-memory:

- You might have a jump instruction which you can execute by adding a number to your program counter. Doing that to the index of an array vs seeking a file is a good use case.
- You may want to optimise your VM's behaviour, and that may involve reading the file more than once. Scanning a list twice vs reading a file twice will be much quicker.
- Depending on opcodes and the grammar of your language you may want to look ahead in a 'cycle' to speed up execution. If that ends up doing two seeks then this could end up degrading performance.

If your file will always be small enough fit in RAM then it's probably worth reading it all into memory. Profile it with a real program and see if it's noticeably faster.

Answer (score 3):

Cache aside, you still have *system calls*. Each `read()` results in a mode switch to trigger the kernel. You can see this with `strace` or another tool to look at system calls.

This might be premature for a 100 KB file though. As always, **test your code** to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

A single call to `read()` will be faster than multiple calls to `read()`. The tradeoff is that with a single call you must be able to fit all data in memory at once, whereas with multiple reads you only have to retain a fraction of the total amount of data. For files that are just a few kilobytes or megabytes, the difference won't be noticeable. For files that are several gigs in size, memory becomes more important.

Also, to do a single read means all of the data must be present, whereas multiple reads can be used to process data as it is streaming in from an external source.

Comment: Does opening the file as a buffered stream reduce the impact of multiple reads?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for performance, I would recommend going through [generators](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators). Since you have small file size, memory would not be any big concern, but its still a good practice. Still reading file from disc multiple times is a definite bottleneck for a scalable solution.